Preserve rich format when joining cell contents in Google Sheets
I'm making a Google Sheets tool that is integrated with Google Forms. You fill out a form, and the sheet does some processing and spits out a richly formatted summary of the input. A lot of this is using hyperlinks.
So, if Recents:D1 is a hyperlink, and Recents:H1 is some bolded text (otherwise treated as a string), then =JOIN(" | ", D1, B1) just returns a string.
Is there any way to combine cells programmatically while still preserving rich formatting?

Try changing your formula into this. =HYPERLINK(JOIN("|", D1, B1)). Please let me know if this works for you, if it is not please share a more detailed view of the data this way the community will have better overview what is going on and what measure should be taken and give better suggestions.

=HYPERLINK(D1, H1) unless there is something we're missing.
